# Redirect only if file exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

images are stored in:

```
/image/gallery/cars/
```

image path is a bit different (see the ID 4 behind cars):

```
/image/gallery/cars-a4/testimage.jpg
```

I need a silent redirect from:

```
/image/gallery/cars/testimage.jpg
```

to

```
/image/gallery/cars-a4/testimage.jpg
```

when the file physically exist in

```
/image/gallery/cars/
```

What I tried without success:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/image/gallery/cars/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^image/gallery/cars-a4/(.*)$ image/gallery/cars/$1 [L]
```

The Rule seems to be right but I miss a condition, because even when the file is not exist the redirect works and is giving a 404.

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `%1` to a `$1` in your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/image/gallery/cars/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^image/gallery/cars-a4/(.*)$ image/gallery/cars/$1 [L]
```

Comment: like a charm...once again, thank you very much Jon Lin